# Delete row if the previous row has same value/string (for each group)

Tags: r

For each group i want to delete the row if value matches the previous row

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
y <- c("A","B","B","A","A","A","B","B")
xy <- data.frame(x,y)
colnames(xy)<-c("group","value")
xy
```

It should result in

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
y <- c("A","B","A","A","B")
result_df <- data.frame(x,y)
colnames(result_df)<-c("group","value")
result_df
```

Think I have to apply something with lag, but i dont get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each group i want to delete the row if value matches the previous row

You can deduplicate on runs with `rleidv` from the data.table package:

```
xy[!duplicated(data.table::rleidv(xy)), ]

  group value
1     1     A
2     1     B
4     1     A
5     2     A
7     2     B
```

If there are other columns in `xy`, you'd do `rleidv(xy, c("group", "value"))` to dedupe only on those.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that `lag` is an appropriate way to do this comparison.  First you `group_by` your group value so it filters within each category, then filter out those where the value is equal to `lag(value)` aka the previous value.  The `is.na` statement compensates for the first lag value being NA in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
xy %>% group_by(group) %>%  filter(value!=lag(value) | is.na(lag(value)))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
#   group value
#   <dbl> <fct>
# 1  1.00 A    
# 2  1.00 B    
# 3  1.00 A    
# 4  2.00 A    
# 5  2.00 B
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n <- nrow(xy)
xy[!c(FALSE, rowMeans(xy[-1, ] == xy[-n, ]) == 1), ]
  group value
1     1     A
2     1     B
4     1     A
5     2     A
7     2     B
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple base R solution.

```
xy[c(0, diff(duplicated(xy)))<1,]

  group value
1     1     A
2     1     B
4     1     A
5     2     A
7     2     B
```